# Unable to compile and publish my Typescript library using webpack or TSC

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

Ive created a library that helps to trace an object state using rx streams and
Im trying to publish it to npm community.

you can check this out [In my github repo](https://github.com/lihaibh/traceable)

I want to compile my library to a single Javascript file and also create a declaration file ".d.ts" for Typescript users.
As i understand, when running `$ npm publish` i release my entire repository. what i want is to release the dist folder with the library source and declaration file and so the end users will be able to debug my library if necessary through their code so i need also source map.

So first i need to compile my src directory to a single javascript file and i have 2 ways to do so, using tsc or with webpack.

**What ive tried so far and you should know:**

I used module alias, configured in tsconfig.json.
I separated the library's bussiness logic to multiple files.
I wanted to import internal library's modules using "@lib" prefix.

so in my tsconfig.json i added:

```
 "paths": {
      "@lib/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
```

That alone cause some problems.

first of all running the command:

```
$ tsc src/index.ts
```

doesn't work at all and it shows me an error:

```
src/index.ts(3,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@lib/state-traceable'.
src/index.ts(4,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@lib/traceable-decorator'. src/index.ts(5,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@lib/effect-decorator'.
src/index.ts(6,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@lib/meta'.
```

yet running the command:

```
$ tsc
```

does actually works but it compiles each source file and create declaration file for each one of them.
Additionally, it preserves the path alias "@lib/*" instead of compiling it to something javscript compatible with relative paths "../", "./" etc...

**Using webpack:**

I succeed to bundle all my library sources to a single file and get rid of the "@lib" prefix however im not able to create a single declaration file.
im using "awesome-typescript-loader" plugin for webpack.

I created an issue, thought its a bug but i yet received any response from them:
https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/559

Also tried to get some help from Gitter chats, Typescript community, "awesome-typescript-loader" library has no dedicated chat but couldn't find any useful information. Most of the examples ive seen, Typescript library publishers used to create a single file in their source directory: "index.ts" and it makes life easier because you can use tsc and compile that single file to a javascript file.

I hope i will find salvation here.

**Some general info about the environment itself:**

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Node Version: 9.5.0

npm version: 5.6.0

webpack version: 4.2.0

Comment: The reason `$ tsc` works but `$ tsc src/index.ts` fails is because the second is ignoring your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: so what is the proper way to compile everything to a single js file? running the command: `$ tsc -p "./" index.ts` doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the path configuration like below

```
"paths": {
  "@lib/state-traceable": ["src/state-traceable.ts"],
  "@lib/meta": ["src/meta.ts"],
  "@lib/effect-decorator": ["src/effect-decorator.ts"],
  "@lib/traceable-decorator": ["src/traceable-decorator.ts"],
  "@lib/contracts/*": ["src/contracts/*"],
  "@lib/utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
  "@lib/rx-operators/*": ["src/rx-operators/*"]
},
```

Comment: but it doesnt create single javascript file, is it the right way to have multiple js files in the dist directory?

Comment: you can ng-packagr for your scenario

Comment: it feels me wrong to use something that built for Angular applications for a generic library source. Is there no way to achieve the goal with webpack or other means?